# What is the difference between “quelques” and “quelques-uns”?

Tags: usage, pronoms, adjectifs, déterminants

According to the dictionary, they both mean 'some'.

Answer (score 3):

**Quelque(s)** is an indefinite determiner, translatable as "some" or "a few". It's always attached to a noun phrase: Il y a quelque temps (some times ago); J'ai bien quelques idées, mais... (I have a few idea, but...); Je suis parti en vacance avec quelques amies (I went on holyday with a few friends (f.))

**Quelques-un(e)s** is an indefinite pronoun. It stands alone, in place of a noun phrase, and can refer to animates and inanimates both. Il y en a toujours quelques-uns qui n'ont pas d'appétit (There's always a few that don't have any appetite); Des voitures sans plaques ? J'en ai vu quelques-unes, mais pas tant que ça (Plateless cars? I saw a few, but not that many). The singular is *quelqu'un*, which, like its English counterpart *someone*, can only be used to refer to a human being. Otherwise you use *un(e)*, much like you'd use *one* in English.

*Chaque* and *chacun* have a similar relationship, as do *mon* and *le mien* (and the rest of the possessives), or *tous les* /tulɛ(z)/ and *tous* /tus/. Note that English generally has a different word for each member of of these determiner/pronoun pairs (each/each one; my/mine; every/everyone). "Some" is a bit of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Both quantify countable objects. Both qualify several but small amount of objects

The difference is mostly about the construction of your sentence.
Indeed, `quelques-uns` is used to refers to another stuff.

Example :

> "J'ai pris quelques pommes dans le jardin, tu en veux?"
>
> "Non merci, j'en ai déjà mangé quelques-uns"

`quelques` means "some" without any kind of explanations.
The speaker picked up somme apples.

`quelques-uns` is built with `en`. `en` refers to the apples, and `-uns` refers to `en`. they have exactly the same meaning, the second speaker could have answered :

> "Non merci, j'ai déjà mangé quelques pommes"

Both answers have exactly the same meaning.
But frenchs hate redundancies, so he tries not to repeat "apple" to refers to the same object

Another example :

> "Il me faudrait quelques-uns de tes hommes"

*uns* refers to hommes

> "Tu as des vis?
>
> "Oui"
>
> "Il m'en faudrait quelques-unes"

*unes* refers to en refers to vis (a screw) =feminine

Comment: When speaking about apples (pommes) or screws (vis), you need to accord *uns*. Here, you would say `"J'ai pris quelques pommes dans le jardin, tu en veux?` `- Non merci, j'en ai déjà mangé quelques-unes"` and `Il m'en faudrait quelques-unes`

Comment: `uns` refers to a noun, so you have to accord `uns` with this noun. Une pomme, une vis gives `unes`. Un homme gives `uns`.
Keep in mind : `uns`, `unes` are always plural

Comment: @ThomasFrancois is saying that your examples are grammatically incorrect. Yours says "quleques-uns" instead of the correct, "quelques-unes" for "pommes" and "vis".